# loop dataframe to shift columns by incrementally increasing value

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to create a loop that will take the transposed dataframe and do the following:

1. shift first column down by 1
2. shift second column down by 2
3. shift third column down by 3
4. shift fourth column down by 4
5. fill blanks with np.nan
6. add additional row names resulting from the shifted columns

Desired outcome visual included below.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(3), freq='D')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
data1 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
data2 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
data3 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': days, 'col2': data, 'col3': data1, \
                   'col4': data2, 'col5': data3})
df = df.set_index('Date')

df= df.T


## loop to shift rows down and fill with np.nan
#for i in range(0, df.shape[1]):
#    df = df.shift(1)  

print(df)
```

[desired outcome visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VundB.png)

Comment: I suggest you improve your question,especially try to don’t add a picture, Have a look here => [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the column names and pass that to the shift function (+1) since it starts at zero.

```
for c, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    df[col] = df[col].shift(c+1)
```

Comment: This is a helpful partial answer. The data are now clipped where the shifted values extend below the original df. Perhaps need to append new rows prior to the loop?

Comment: for c, col in enumerate(df1.columns):
    df1[col] = df1[col].shift(c+1)
    df1 = df1.append({'x':np.nan}, ignore_index=True)